# Outgoing CALL_STATE

Tags: android, android-activity, android-broadcast, telephonymanager

How can I access the current status of an outgoing call (dialing, active, etc.)?

In my application I want it that all the LEDs on the device are inactive for the duration of the "call-active status", but during the "dialing status" and after the call is ended the LEDs should be on. I need to read out (or capture) the status - but how?

I have already read that one can not question the `CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK`.

Is it possible to infer the status via the GUI (phone screens)?
Or is there another possibility?

I know that this is not a new topic but I´m only looking for the "dialing/active/disconnected" statuses - the rest (holding, alerting, incoming,...) don´t matter.

If the gui changes there must be a possibility to read that "changing behaviour out" and use it .... or am I too naive?

Answer (score 0):

You can use AudioManager to get the current audio state, effectively seeing if you are currently in a call or not.

```
mAudioManager.getMode() == AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL
```

if that returns true, then your user is in a call, otherwise they aren't. I know this isn't a full solution to your problem, but it might help if other things are not possible.

Comment: thanks for this creative approach!that could partially solve my issue!do you know at which call-status TRUE is returned?-At the "active" or at the "dealing" status?

Comment: I wasn't sure, so I tested it using an app I'm currently building.  It seems that it goes into AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL as soon as it connects and begins ringing.  When it says "dialing" but there is no timer, it is still in the default audio mode.

Comment: thanks for testing! I have also tried to test your approach,but unfortunately I did not get a good result. It seems like the `AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL` starts directly after pushing the "green phone button to start a call" --therefore, this approach is not scoring a better result than the `CALL_STATE_IDLE` and `CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK`. or am I missing something?

Comment: I don't think you are.  Ah well, it was an idea at least